# How do I find where a string is put inside a string?

Tags: string, python-2.7

Learn Python the Hard Way, exercise 6.2-4:

```
x = "There are %d types of people." 10
binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = "Those who know %s and those who %s." % (binary, do_not)

print x
print y

print "I said: %r." % x
print "I also said: '%s'." % y

hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

print" joke_evaluation % hilarious

w = "This is the left side of..."
e = "a string with a right side."

print w + e
```

2.Find all the places where a string is put inside a string. There are four places. 
3.Are you sure there's only four places? How do you know? Maybe I like lying.
4.Explain why adding the two string w and e with + makes a longer string.

I can't tell if he's lying or not here, because to me it looks like there are 6 times. So can anyone tell me how many times a string is put inside a string and where?

Also if it's not to much trouble could you explain why two string with + makes a longer string.

Comment: Your first line contains a typo. I'm not lying about that.

Comment: Also this line: `print" joke_evaluation % hilarious`

Answer (score 0):

So we know on the first line than %d is not putting a string inside a string, as we're putting a decimal value into a string. We also know that %s is used to represent a string, so what we have left is the %r.

```
print "I said: %r." % x
```

Uses x to fill in %r, and x was previously defined to be a string. But with

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"
```

the joke_evaluation variable is a string while hilarious is a boolean value. Now `print" joke_evaluation % hilarious`converts the boolean into a printable format for displaying, but I think what he means in this exercises makes this not inserting a string into another string.